# There are a free and locally tool to create insights from Spring Boot Java Application's Log like Splunk?

Tags: java, spring, logging, dashboard

I'm seeking for a good tool to create dashboard, insights and clearly information from Application logs. Azure Insights and Splunk are good options but I want something light and free to use locally. Somebody have any suggestion?

Comment: ELK stack can be good solution

Answer (score 0):

See also : elk stack (elasticsearch logstash and kibana)

https://www.elastic.co/elastic-stack